# Ayuda con consulta de fecha Sql developer

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql

[image: Mostrar:][image: Tablas:]Necesito ayuda con un código de consulta donde se me plantea lo siguiente:

De acuerdo con lo requerido por el usuario, el sistema debe contar **con un informe que se ejecutará el último día hábil de cada mes y deberá mostrar la cantidad de departamentos por edificio que no han cancelado los gastos comunes del mes anterior.** Por ejemplo, si el informe se ejecuta en Junio de este año, el informe debe visualizar el total de departamentos que no han pagado las gastos comunes del mes de Mayo de este año, si el informe se ejecuta en Noviembre de este año, el informe debe mostrar el total de departamentos que no han pagado las gastos comunes correspondientes a Octubre de este año, etc. Es decir, el informe en forma paramétrica debe ser capaz de obtener la información del mes anterior a la fecha en que se ejecute. 
El informe debe indicar el nombre del edificio, la comuna en la cual se ubica, run y nombre completo del administrador, el total de departamentos que posee el edificio y cuántos departamentos no han pagado los gastos comunes. La información se requiere en el formato que se indica en el ejemplo y ordenada alfabéticamente por comuna y nombre del edificio. El informe del ejemplo se ejecutó el último día hábil de Agosto del presente año por lo tanto, está mostrando el total de departamentos que no pagaron los gastos comunes de Julio del presente año.

Mi problema es con la última columna, no sé como extraer lo que se pide (total de dptos que no han cancelado sus gastos comunes de forma parametrica segun fecha)..

Hasta ahora mi codigo lleva esto:

```
SELECT UPPER(e.edi_nombre_edificio) "NOMBRE EDIFICIO", 
c.nombre_comuna "COMUNA", 
TO_CHAR(a.adm_numrun, '99G999G999') || '-' || a.adm_dvrun "RUT_ADMINISTRADOR",
INITCAP (a.adm_pnombre) || ' ' | | INITCAP(a.adm_snombre) || ' ' || 
INITCAP (a.adm_apellido_paterno) || ' ' || 
INITCAP (a.adm_apellido_materno) "NOMBRE_ADMINISTRADOR",
COUNT(d.total_dormitorios) "TOTAL DEPTOS"
FROM edificio e JOIN comuna c
ON (e.id_comuna = c.id_comuna)
JOIN administrador a 
ON a.adm_numrun = e.adm_numrun
JOIN departamento d 
ON (d.id_edificio = e.id_edificio)
JOIN
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano y espero puedan ayudar las imagenes adjuntadas.

Comment: Es importante que añadas info de las tablas sobre las que consultas y datos de prueba

Comment: serviriría con las imagenes que eh añadido?

Comment: Desde un móvil es casi imposible leer. Procura siempre usar texto : sentencias de creación de tablas, datos de prueba, etc. Siempre como texto